# Convert JSON to Array Xcode

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am trying to implement two side by side UIPickerViews, one for Type and the other for Subtype.  Each is an array of strings

```
var typePickerData: [String] = [String]()
var subtypePickerData: [String] = [String]()
```

Each is a pretty simple array of names:

```
typePickerData = ["Monitor","Keyboard","Mouse"]
```

When the viewDidLoad fires or when a new Type is selected, the app makes a remote db call and I get a response containing JSON of subtype names which I want to use to populate and reload the subtype picker.

I am stuck on converting the response into subtypePickerData

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
if let jsonResponse = try? decoder.decode([String].self, from: data) {
        
    print("parse subtype response \(jsonResponse)")
        
    subtypePickerData = jsonResponse
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.subtypePicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here converting the JSON response to subtypePickerData?

this is what I am getting from the remote call

```
result Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x281370e70>( { name = Monitor; },{ name = "AV Accessories"; },{ name = Computer; },{ name = "Monitor Stands"; },{ name = "Bracket/Mount"; },{ name = Screen; }
```

Here is my updated code after solving issue

```
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    if let jsonResponse = try? decoder.decode(Subtypes.self, from: data) {
        SubtypeList = jsonResponse.result
        self.subtypePickerData = SubtypeList.map{$0.Name}
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.subtypePicker.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong exactly? Is `jsonResponse` nil? Why `try?` and not a proper `do`/`try`/`catch` to see if there is an error? And what's the JSON looking like?

Comment: result
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x281370e70>(
{
    name = Monitor;
},{
    name = "AV Accessories";
},{
    name = Computer;
},{
    name = "Monitor Stands";
},{
    name = "Bracket/Mount";
},{
    name = Screen;
}

Comment: What's that print? Where does it come from? What's your API call? And your JSON isn't a `[String]`, just replace `try?` with `try!` you'll see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor response seems to be not type of `[String]` but an array of custom objects. You first need to create a struct to decode your response data to.

```
struct NameContainer{
    var name: String
}
```

then do:

```
//change decoding to String array to decoding array of custom object NameContainer
if let jsonResponse = try? decoder.decode([NameContainer].self, from: data) {
        
    print("parse subtype response \(jsonResponse)")
        
    subtypePickerData = jsonResponse.map{$0.name} // Map your objects to strings and assign them
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.subtypePicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

---

Remarks:

- Never use `try?` this will obfuscate all errors. Use a proper do/catch block, handle the error or mark your function `throws` and handle the error up the chain.

Answer (score 1):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.subtypePicker.reloadAllComponents()

Bracket/Mount"; },{ name = Screen; } –
```

Comment: How does this answer adress the question?

Comment: Why the random partial string literal? Was this copied from somewhere?